# How can we remove name space in level 1 elements of the xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xml

```
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <UserInfo xmlns="">
      <name>ss</name>
      <addr>XXXXXX</addr>
     </UserInfo>
</Request>
```

I want the output xml as

```
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <UserInfo>
          <name>ss</name>
          <addr>XXXXXX</addr>
         </UserInfo>
    </Request>
```

Please help me in xsl..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input and output are semantically the same, but if you want to remove that `xmlns=""`, this will work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserInfo>
    <name>ss</name>
    <addr>XXXXXX</addr>
  </UserInfo>
</Request>
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your help.But i have tried with another xml,It is not working with this xml..please help..

<Request xmlns="http://hgkg.ghg.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
   <AppointmentInfo xmlns="">
    
      <AppointmentId/>
    
      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    
      <Division>A</Division>
 </AppointmentInfo>
</Request>

Comment: @SrivatsavaSesham: That's not (well-formed) XML. Also, clarify "not working". What result did you get?

Comment: i am getting same
<Request xmlns="http://hgkg.ghg.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
   
   <AppointmentInfo xmlns="">
    
      
      <AppointmentId/>
    
      
      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    
      
      <Division>A</Division>
 
   </AppointmentInfo>

</Request>

Comment: +1 good answer. Note `match="*[parent::*]"` is equivalent to `match="*/*"`.

Comment: @Sri: now your input and output are not semantically the same, which is why the solution offered doesn't work. Do you want `<AppointmentInfo>` to be in the `hgkg.ghg.com` namespace, or in no namespace?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28125/discussion-between-srivatsava-sesham-and-larsh)