# How can we convert XML elements into a different namespace in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I have an input xml

```
<Request xmlns="http://hgkg.ghg.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <AppointmentInfo xmlns="">

      <AppointmentId/>

      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>

      <Division>A</Division>
    </AppointmentInfo>
  <AppointDate xmlns="">
   <Day>Monday</Day>
    <Date>April 2</Date>
  <AppointDate>

</Request>
```

I need output like this

```
<Request xmlns="http://hgkg.ghg.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <AppointmentInfo>

      <AppointmentId/>

      <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>

      <Division>A</Division>
    </AppointmentInfo>
    <AppointDate>
       <Day>Monday</Day>
        <Date>April 2</Date>
      <AppointDate>
</Request>
```

i just want to remove xmlns="" in that and assume response AppointmentInfo and AppointDate are in hgkg namespace.I want to transform to it..
please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [JLRishe's earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15978939/423105), you could try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(/*)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would mean, each element that is not the outermost element (`match="*/*"`) is copied to an output element with the same name, but with the namespace of the outermost element (`namespace-uri(/*)`).

See if that works...

Comment: @Ironman: You're welcome... I guess you changed your name. :-) Next time, tell the person who gives you these requests, to specify them not in terms of adding/removing namespace declarations, but in terms of what namespace each element needs to be in. The latter is what XML tools (like XSLT) are designed to be able to predictably interpret and control. The former is surface structure that could change at a serializer's whim.